# WCF DataService "Time" datatype problem

Tags: wcf, web-services, entity-framework, rest, wcf-data-services

I'm trying to expose data from SQL Server database by Entity Framework plus **WCF DataService**. All is ok as long as I don't add a table with a field of "Time" datatype to the EF model. In this case I get a runtime error:

***The property 'Time' on type 'XXX' is of type 'Time' which is not a supported primitive type***

Is there a fix for this issue or should I use a traditional web service in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered here: [How do I expose a TimeSpan through a WCF Data Service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5587433/how-do-i-expose-a-timespan-through-a-wcf-data-service)

Comment: Does that mean I should each time manually edit the Model.Designer.cs file which is autogenerated by Entity Framework?