# WCF DataService with Entity Framework: TimeSpan support

Tags: asp.net, .net, wcf-ria-services, wcf-data-services

I am trying to create a WCF Data Service over an Entity Framework Object context that exposes a number of System.TimeSpan properties. However, when I try to access the service, I get the following error: 'The property 'ScheduledDepartureTime' on type 'DepotRoute' is of type 'Time' which is not a supported primitive type.'

I have tried using DataServiceConfiguration.RegisterKnownType(typeof(TimeSpan)) as well as DataServiceConfiguration.EnableTypeAccess(typeof(TimeSpan).FullName) but neither of these seem to make any difference - I still get the error...

```
public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config) {

    config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("*", EntitySetRights.AllRead);
    config.SetServiceOperationAccessRule("*", ServiceOperationRights.All);
    config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V2;
    config.UseVerboseErrors = true;

    config.RegisterKnownType(typeof(TimeSpan));
    config.EnableTypeAccess(typeof(TimeSpan).FullName);

    RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("Data", new DataServiceHostFactory(), typeof(Data)));

}
```

Although my context is being generated as a DbContext, I have overriden CreateDataSource to expose the ObjectContext rather than creating the service as DataService...

```
protected override ObjectContext CreateDataSource() {

    var context = new MercuryContext().ObjectContext;
    context.ContextOptions.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

    return context;

}
```

I have however also tried exposing a service based upon a standard EF Model but this too makes no difference. I have even tried it using VS11 Develop Preview - this too cannot expose my properties.

What am I missing? There must be some way to do this.

Comment: May be a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5587433/how-do-i-expose-a-timespan-through-a-wcf-data-service

Comment: JayC: Having just looked at it, I do not think that it is. This is specifically about EF generated properties whereas the original post appears to expose hand crafted properties which could be modified in the code (whereas my properties are generated).

Answer (score 0):

EF can't use the TimeSpan type in a query; you will need to convert the TimeSpan to the corresponding DateTime value that it represents.

Comment: TheGeekYouNeed: My problem is not with querying the EF model, but with exposing it through WCF Data Services. I do not need to query based upon the time fields.